# list comprehension through Cartesian product keeping one value fixed

Tags: python

Python's syntax for iterating through data structures with multiple values in each element is beautiful. Typing `for x, y in XcrossY` just feels right. I was wondering if there was a clever way to iterate through one of the sets while keeping the other value fixed. Specifically.

```
     while q not in F:

            choices = list()

            for i in sigma:

                    if (q, i) in delta:

                            choices.append(i)

            choices = tuple(choices)

            # more pythonic way?
            #choices = tuple([i for (q, i) in delta])
```

The problem with the commented code is that it does not leave q fixed. It just iterates through it. Replacing q with a constant value manually throws `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`. I'd like to replace the 5 lines preceding it though. Is there a clever way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Leave that part alone and use a constant somewhere else, e.g. `[(3,i) for q,i in delta]`. If you want, you can name the unused variable `_` to make it a bit more clear that you don't plan to refer to it. If you don't want to use a constant value at all, your original code of `[i for (q, i) in delta]` is fine (again, replacing the unused variable with `_` if you want).